# How to populate dropdownlist with stored procedure and with class file in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to populate state and city according to country selected .I have done this but now I want to create this with stored Procedure and with class file .. Can someone please help ?

Comment: what do u mean by class file?

Comment: we can create methods in class file and you have to just pass object of that class file in .aspx.cs file

Comment: @Brinda What have you tried, please share your code.

Comment: @Brinda Please mark this as accepted answer, there will be a tick mark beside my answer, so that it would be help full for users in future also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Sample Prcedure to create a Dropdown of Language:

**SP**

```
CREATE proc sp_getlangusges
as
select LanguageId,Languages from Languages
```

**CS**

```
public DataSet Getalllanguages()
    {
        try
        {
          //  you loginc to connect to database using sp
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

In **Aspx.cs**

```
  Classfinename objEvents = new Classfinename ();

private void BindContrydropdown()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dsLang = objEvents.Getalllanguages();
            if (dsLang.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ddllang.DataTextField = "Languages";
                ddllang.DataValueField = "LanguageId";
                ddllang.Items.Clear();
                ddllang.DataSource = dsLang;
                ddllang.DataBind();
                ddllang.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  }
    }
```

Comment: @Brinda , as you are new i am helping you, now you try with the state and implement the same process. so that you wont stuck anywhere, this is a basic example so that you will get an idea and you will start implementing by your own. Happy Coding !!